# stretch(overflow if data exceeds) a textfield in jasper reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a textfield above subreport in detail section, the textfield doesn't stretch if data overflow due to the subreport, If i remove the subreport it works as expected. What should i do to stretch the textfield.

this is my detail section:-

```xml
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="false" evaluationTime="Now" hyperlinkType="None"  hyperlinkTarget="Self" >
    <reportElement
                    style="dNew"
                    mode="Opaque"
                    x="1290"
                    y="20"
                    width="111"
                    height="20"
                    key="value-6"
                    stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight"
                    isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
    <box></box>
    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Top" markup="html">
        <font fontName="Arial" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[( $F{STANDARD_CONTROLS}!=null ? $F{STANDARD_CONTROLS} : "-" )]]>
    </textFieldExpression>
</textField>
<subreport  isUsingCache="true">
    <reportElement
                    mode="Transparent"
                    x="0"
                    y="40"
                    width="320"
                    height="15"
                    key="subreport-1"
                    isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
    <subreportParameter  name="requestListId">
        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{SPREADSHEET_REPORT_ID}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
    </subreportParameter>
    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
    <subreportExpression  class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{subReportPath}]]>
    </subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

Answer (score 0):

set subreport's position type = "float".. try with this it will work.